# Move UIImageView when user start touch ON the imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have some imageviews in a UIView. This is my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint startPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self];
    imageview.center = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
}
```

With this the user can click anywhere on screen and the imageview will teleport to the touch location and move from there. I want to limit it so that it will only respond if the user starts clicking ON the imageview. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a gesture recognizer added to the image view. If you use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` it will be fired when the user starts dragging from inside the image view, and you can use the `locationOfTouch:inView:` method to work out where to position the dragged image view

update with more detail:
A UIGestureRecognizer (abstract class with a few subclasses included, or you can make your own) is an object which is attached to a UIView, and is capable of recognising gestures (e.g. UIPanGestureRecogniser knows when a user is panning, UISwipGestureRecognizer knows when a user is swiping).

You create a gesture recognizer and add it to a view like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognizerMethod:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

then in your gestureRecognizerMethod implementation you can check the state of teh gesture, and adjust the position of the image view

```
- (void)gestureRecognizerMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recogniser
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        self.imageView.center = touchLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please give an example of this can be done, I'm a bit new to objective-c..?

Comment: do I need the touchmoved method?

Comment: BTW if I have multiple imageviews, do I need one method for each imageview ?

Comment: you can use the same method, but you'll need to check which image view is being dragged. the view the recognizer is attached to can be found by calling [recognizer view];